# What makes DT[order(.)] call data.table's fast order instead of base::order?

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table package's documentation for `setorder` states:

> x[order(.)] is now optimised internally to use data.table's fast
>   order by default. data.table always reorders in C-locale. To sort by
>   session locale, use x[base::order(.)] instead.

I am curious to know how simply writing `order` in this context causes a function different from R's own (base) `order` to be called.

I could have explained this behavior if data.table had exported its own function called `order`, thereby masking `base::order`, but this does not appear to be happing (in any case, there is no such thing as `data.table::order`). How, then, is the meaning of `order` changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L516) is it, worked into `\`[.data.table\``.

Comment: `DT[...]` takes `...` and parses it according to its own rules as documented. Similarly, you could write `mean` and end up using `gmean`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you both! Based on data.table's check `isub[[1L]] == as.name("order")` I would think that `forder` is no longer used if I nest `order`, e.g. `DT[rev(order(.)]`, whereas it would be if I used `DT[order(., decreasing=TRUE)]` -- does that seem right?

Comment: Yup, I think so. Turn on `DT[..., verbose=TRUE]` to see if it's used or not.

Comment: Actually data.tables `forder` was already added as an addition method to base R `order` in [V 3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) "*The radix sort algorithm and implementation from data.table (forder) replaces the previous radix (counting) sort and adds a new method for order(). Contributed by Matt Dowle and Arun Srinivasan, the new algorithm supports logical, integer (even with large values), real, and character vectors. It outperforms all other methods, but there are some caveats (see ?sort).*"

Comment: It is very common for packages to use functions internally that aren't exported. If that function is evaluated within an exported function, it will be evaluated in the package environment and thus have access to the package internal functions. That's why writing `x[order(.)]` will use `data.table:::order` whereas writing `with(DT, order(.))` would use `base::order`.